# Stored procedure activity ADF V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using a stored procedure activity for ADF v2 pipeline. Now issue here is whenever the pipeline fails at the stored procedure activity I'm not getting the complete error details. Below is the JSON output of that stored procedure activity:

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
    "executionDuration": 416,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
},
"billingReference": {
    "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
    "billableDuration": [
        {
            "meterType": "AzureIR",
            "duration": 0.11666666666666667,
            "unit": "Hours"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Please let me know how do I get the error details for the stored procedure activity for ADF v2 pipeline?

Comment: you should include the stored procedure code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should throw the exception in your stored procedure code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This worked now after implementing THROW within my stored procedure. I can now see the error details from ADF pipeline..